# Escaping the path/url when rendering an inline background image in Rails Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, paperclip

I have the following Rails view in an ERB template where I set an inline style background image.

(The `url` is hard-coded for demonstration, but in reality it's generated via a [paperclip attachment](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) in my `Photo` model (e.g. `photo.source.url(:medium)`)

```
<% url = "/system/photos/sources/000/000/008/medium/20160820_131939" %>

<div class="photo" background-image: url(<%= url %>);>
</div>
```

This ends up rendering the following `<div>`

[image]

Copying the above from Chrome's inspector reveals that it's being generated as key-value pairs

```
<div class="photo" background-image:="" url(="" system="" photos="" sources="" 000="" 008="" medium="" 20160820_131939);="">
</div>
```

Why does Rails do this? It seems to be trying to escape the forward slashes in the path?

1. I tried various forms of `html_safe` and escaping/unescaping, but no luck.
2. `image_path` and `asset_path` aren't applicable here because my path is generated by the paperclip gem which will correctly yield the right path in all environments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background-image` property is CSS and needs to be within a style attribute.
i.e. `<div class="photo" style="background-image: url('<%= url %>');" >`

Comment: sigh... been staring at this for 30 minutes and I completely missed that -_-
Thanks for the catch.

Comment: this can be abused if there is a single quote `'` in the `url`